# Datastream from cloud SQL (PostgreSQL) to Bigquery BIGQUERY_TOO_MANY_PRIMARY_KEYS/BIGQUERY_UNSUPPORTED_TYPE_FOR_PRIMARY_KEY

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql, google-datastream

I just started to experiment with the new datastream from CloudSQL (PostgreSQL) to Bigquery and I am having many errors when starting the stream. Mostly `BIGQUERY_UNSUPPORTED_TYPE_FOR_PRIMARY_KEY` and `BIGQUERY_TOO_MANY_PRIMARY_KEYS`. Some of the table are just being created when other do not even if they have the same primary key type (created by bigserial PRIMARY KEY)

[image]

Comment: I have exactly the same issue for postgres table with 1 primary key (signle column) and 4 unique index (single column each). So I tried to remove all unique indexes and it works now, so, let's check if you don't have 4 unique index in your source table (primary key included)

Comment: yes @Fryck I have one unique index. How did you proceed ? By updating your source database ?

Comment: have you found another way other than to remove the unique indexes?

Comment: Note that google is aware, issue tracked here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/250938168?pli=1